# TipTap using name tag

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, tiptap

I've noticed that you cant use the name tag on TipTap which means you cant use it to send data through forms in laravel. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
<tiptap-vuetify
      v-model="content"
      :extensions="extensions"
      :toolbar-attributes="{ color: '#bf1256' }"
      :name="module.name"
      :id="module.id"
    />
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add an hidden input with the content ?

Comment: <input type="hidden" :name="module.name" :value="content">
Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<tiptap-vuetify
      v-model="module.markdownContent"
      :extensions="extensions"
      :id="module.id"
      :toolbar-attributes="{ color: '#bf1256' }"
    />
<input type="hidden" :name="module.name" :value="module.markdownContent">
```

This fixed it